# How to introduce keyboard functions in Opengl code

Tags: opengl, text, keyboard

I am new to opengl I tried to make an isosurface by reading from a text file .now I want to introdude keyboard functions in my code so that I can rotate an do all that stuffs. please tell me from where i can study that or give me a sample code

Sudhanshu

Comment: OpenGL does not have anything to do with Keyboards. What are you using to create your OpenGL context (SDL, ...), what OS are you on?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL only deals with drawing stuff. It gives you a canvas and some primitive drawing tools. Nothing more. Anything beyond that is the task of the user interface system provided by the OS.

Maybe you're using GLUT and are mislead by its name. GLUT is not part of OpenGL; it's a rudimentary framework aimed at developing simple OpenGL example programs, but that's about it.